# How to extend a user defined class in a XSD

Tags: java, xsd

I want to generate a java class xsd such that it also extended a user defined class in some specific package...

Comment: We need more information - what toolkit/framework are you using?  JAXB (and if so which implementation, the reference impl, or EclipseLink MOXy, ...), xmlbeans, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add behaviour/bussiness logic have a look at this beautifull stackoverflow answer here: [How can I extend Java code generated by JAXB, CXF or Hibernate tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780567/how-can-i-extend-java-code-generated-by-jaxb-cxf-or-hibernate-tools)