# jaxb binding to override the datatype List<Object> to String

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

jaxb unmarshals

```
    <xs:complexType name="Test" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
         <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <attributes.../>
    </xs:complexType>
```

as 
    `protected List<Object> content`;

My jxb bindings file is :

```
  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Test']">

                <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType name="java.lang.String"></jxb:baseType>
                </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
```

and this makes the java equivalent as

```
protected List<String> content;
```

Is there a way I can get it to be `protected String content` ?

Comment: Why use an `xs:any` if you want a `String`? If you don't want a `Collection` then add a `maxOccurs="1"` to tell JAXB there there is only one.

Comment: The problem is that in future we might need a `Collection` which contains `Strings` along with other `tags`.But for now I want to make a hack to get a simple `String`.
Changing the schema is one option.Is it even possible using the binding file?

Comment: So it looks like there is no way to convert a List to a String after all and it makes sense. This question does not make a lot of sense.Sorry for that. It there a way to mark this question as "ignore" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the generated class as described in this stackoverflow question:
[How can I extend Java code generated by JAXB, CXF or Hibernate tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780567/how-can-i-extend-java-code-generated-by-jaxb-cxf-or-hibernate-tools) That should give you acces to the protected field

Comment: Right. That seems to be a reasonable solution. I was wondering if there is a way to do it just by using the bindings functionality.